# Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'IBM.Data.DB2' is either not registered in the machine or application config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-framework-version

I have a C#-Project (.NET Framework 4.5.2) with Entity Framework 6. I like to open this file with the EDM designer to see the all the entities for the selected tables and the relationships between them.

Here are the "Open With" Dialog to choose the program. I selected the "ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer (Default)" which is the default program for open '.edmx'-Extensions in Visual Studio 2022.

[image: ![enter image description here]

If I open the file i get the following error:
[image: ![enter image description here]

For the readability of the error I have described the error here again:

> Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'IBM.Data.DB2' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.    MyExampleApp.Model  D:\Applicatons\dev\Model\MyExampleApp.Model\ExampleModel.edmx.edmx  7

Questions:

- How can I see the inner exception for this error 175?
- How can i fix the error?

Comment: Do you want an honest answer or a productive one? I'd say upgrade away from that 3+ years old codebase. Entity Framework 6 (non-core) has been on life support since 2019. Anyway has your project got https://www.nuget.org/packages/Net.IBM.Data.Db2/ installed? Can you see more exception details in the Output pane?

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster. Thank your for your honest answer. I can't see any error descriptions in the Output pane.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.2-4.6.1 reached [End Of Life in April 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/). It was already a very old version of .NET which couldn't use TLS 1.2 without hacks. `edmx` is a remnant of the very first versions of EF, abandoned several years ago when code-first was introduced in EF 4 (I think). This matters a *lot* because IBM isn't known for long-term support of its .NET drivers. Quite the opposite

Comment: IBMs [own EF docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=framework-microsoft-entity-60-support) use the [EntityFramework.IBM.DB2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.IBM.DB2) package which only supports Entity Framework 6.x. There's no `IBM.Data.DB2`. I suspect you're working on an old project using obsolete drivers. Even IBM doesn't support these any more